# JSX not displaying second p in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to display a div that has in it two paragraphs with different classNames and it displays only the first paragraph.

```css
.notification-container {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999
}

.top-right {
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.bottom-right {
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.top-left {
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in;
  animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.bottom-left {
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in;
  animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.notification {
  background: #fff;
  transition: .3s ease;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
  color: #000;
  opacity: .9;
  background-position: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.notification:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer
}

.notification-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 18px;
}

.notification-message {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: 18px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.notification-image {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.notification-image img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.toasts {
  height: 50px;
  width: 365px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 15px 10px 10px;
}

.notification-container button {
  position: relative;
  right: -.3em;
  top: -.3em;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0
}

@keyframes toast-in-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes toast-in-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="notification toasts bottom-left">
  //here there is some more tags...
  <div>
    //this div shows only the first p tag
    <p className="notification-title">first p</p>
    <p className="notification-message">second p</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you present a reproducible example on codesandbox or something?

Comment: Keeping in mind the *minimal* part of [mcve], is all that animation-related CSS necessary for this specific question? If not, it's better to remove it to focus on debugging the actual problem. There also doesn't seem to be any jsx or react in this question. Maybe you left something out, or you meant to use "class" instead of "className"

Comment: @camille i thought that maybe the css of the outer div is stopping the second p of being showed

Comment: Text in your example is white for some reason, remove `max-height: 100px;` from .notification, if this is what you mean

Comment: Actually on second look, the text is white on a white background. Looking at it with devtools, the second paragraph is there, it's just the box it's in is too small so it gets cut off

Answer (score 2):

Just change this code for `.notification` {  `background: red;` `overflow: auto;`} . You can see in below snippet.

```css
.notification-container {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999
}

.top-right {
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.bottom-right {
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.top-left {
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in;
  animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.bottom-left {
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in;
  animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.notification {
  background: red;
  transition: .3s ease;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
  color: #000;
  opacity: .9;
  background-position: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.notification:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer
}

.notification-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 18px;
}

.notification-message {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: 18px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.notification-image {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.notification-image img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.toasts {
  height: 50px;
  width: 365px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 15px 10px 10px;
}

.notification-container button {
  position: relative;
  right: -.3em;
  top: -.3em;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0
}

@keyframes toast-in-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes toast-in-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="notification toasts bottom-left">
  //here there is some more tags...
  <div>
    //this div shows only the first p tag
    <p className="notification-title">first p</p>
    <p className="notification-message">second p</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem you faced is because your `.notification`  `color` matches with `background-color`

Comment: Anytime mate no worries

Answer (score 0):

```css
.notification-container {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999
}

.top-right {
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.bottom-right {
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.top-left {
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in;
  animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.bottom-left {
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in;
  animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.notification {
  background: #fff;
  transition: .3s ease;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
  color: #000;
  opacity: .9;
  background-position: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.notification:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer
}

.notification-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 18px;
  color: #c9c9c9;
}

.notification-message {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: 18px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.notification-image {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.notification-image img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.toasts {
  height: 50px;
  width: 365px;
}

.notification-container button {
  position: relative;
  right: -.3em;
  top: -.3em;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0
}

@keyframes toast-in-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes toast-in-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="notification toasts bottom-left">
  <div>
    <p className="notification-title">first p</p>
    <p className="notification-message">second p</p>
  </div>
</div>
```